# We are unable to display the purchase event in Firebase Analytics RevenueCat

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

1. We are getting this error, which we have described below, from some users. We have added it as a question to your community.

   https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/there-s-a-problem-with-your-configuration-none-of-the- products-registered-in-the-revenuecat-dashboard-could-be-fetched-from-the-play-store-3162

Log:
PlatformException(23, There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details., {code: 23, message: There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details., readableErrorCode: ConfigurationError, readable_error_code: ConfigurationError, underlyingErrorMessage: There's a problem with your configuration. None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from the Play Store. More information: [https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty}](https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty%7D), null)

2. We are unable to display the purchase event in Firebase Analytics, even though we completed the steps in the 'Enable Google Analytics' section of the guide mentioned below

   https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/firebase-integration

Platform: Android